# Images deleted from my application folder are still in the camera gallery

Tags: android, image, file, camera

I am trying to delete images taken through the Camera api and, in principle it does delete them from my application folder but the images are still in the DCIM/camera folder.

I am using an ITOS device with Android version 9.

Here is the code I am using.

```
manifest.xml

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
------
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.cameratest.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

```
@xml/file_paths
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

And this is how I capture the image:

```
private void checkPermissions(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
            } else {
                captureImage();
            }
        } else {
            captureImage();
        }
    }

private void captureImage() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File imageFile = null;
            try {
                imageFile = getImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("TAG", "captureImage ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (imageFile != null) {
                Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, Constants.FILE_AUTHORITY_PROVIDER, imageFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        }

private File getImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp;
        File storageDir =  new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"MisFotos");

        if (! storageDir.exists()){
            if (! storageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        File image = new File(storageDir.getPath() + File.separator + imageFileName + ".jpg");

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d("PHOTO_TAG", "getImageFile: " + currentPhotoPath);
        return image;
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            setPictureToDataBase();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATED**
I save the image path in a database and then retrieve it to delete the file.

And here is the code I use to delete the image in my Picture Adapter

```
public void deletePicture(Picture picture) {
        try {

            myDatabase.deletePicture(picture.getUid());
            String path = picture.getImage();//storageDir.getPath() + File.separator + imageFileName + ".jpg"
            pictures.remove(picture);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (pictures != null && pictures.size()>0){
                listener.onDeleteClick( pictures.size());
            }else {
                listener.onDeleteClick( 0);
            }

            File target = new File(path);

            if (target.exists()) {
                target.delete();
            }
            else {
                Log.d("TAG_DELETE_PICTURE", "ERROR: FILE NOT EXITS");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("deletePicture", "ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

And when I open the device file explorer it is in "MyPhotos" and in DCIM/camera.
[same image, two places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OFwI.png)

It **works correctly when deleting the image from the application folder**, but when looking in DCIM/camera the images are still there and occupy memory.

Am I doing something wrong, is there a way to delete the image saved in **DCIM/camera**?

I want to take the photo, save it only in the folder of the application, and not save it anywhere else. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: change this line `Aquí dejo el código que estoy utilizando.` to english

Comment: There is no code where you try to delete a file. Nor from file system. Nor from MediaStore.

Comment: `in principle it does delete them from my application folder but the images are still in the DCIM/camera folder.` We do not know what you consider to be your application folder as you did not tell but it seems impossible that they would be on two storage places at the same time. Please explain.

Comment: `File storageDir =  new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"MisFotos");
` If you indeed use this then they can never land in a ../DCIM/Camera folder. And they will not be scanned by the MediaStore and hence Gallery apps will not show them.

Comment: If the scenario is indeed as @CommonsWare depicts then you could have a look at the data parameter of onActivityResult. If data.getData() delivers an uri and an uri to the DCIM/Camera folder then you could immediately try to delete that file.

Comment: I am checking and **data** is null. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong

You are launching a camera app via `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. There are tens of thousands of Android device models. There will be dozens of different pre-installed camera apps across those device models, and users can install other camera apps from the Play Store and elsewhere.

What those camera apps do is up to their developers.

In your case, the camera app that you happen to be using is both saving the photo in its normal place and making a copy in the location identified by `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Few camera apps will do this, but it is perfectly legitimate for a camera app to behave that way.

> I want to take the photo, save it only in the folder of the application, and not save it anywhere else. Is there any other way to do this?

Do not use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Instead, use the camera APIs directly or via a wrapper library (Google's CameraX, FotoApparat, CameraKit-Android, etc.).

Comment: As you said, I have chosen to use the Camera API directly, it is the best option. I found a simple example in this tutorial [link](https://youtu.be/_wZvds9CfuE) , to implement the API and save the result on my database. Thanks.